# Routing Error Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, associations

I'm build forum rails app, I have problem with nested resources.

here's `controller/school/forums_controller.rb`

```
  def index
    @forums = Forum.all
  end


  def show
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || 15
    @topics = @forum.topics.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

here's `controller/school/topics_controller.rb`

```
  def new
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @topik = @forum.topiks.build
  end

  def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @topic = @forum.topics.build(params[:topic])
       if @topic.save
          redirect_to school_forum_topic_path(@topic)
        else
          render :action => "new"
        end
  end

  def show
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Here's `routes.rb`

```
get '/forum' => 'school/forums#index', :as => :forum_subdomain

namespace :school, :path => '/' do
        resources :forums, :path => '/forum', :only => [:show] do
          resources :topics
        end
end


 forum_subdomain GET    /forum(.:format)
                        school/forums#index {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                    school_forum_topics GET    /fr/:forum_id/topics(.:
format)                 school/topics#index {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                                           POST   /forum/:forum_id/topics(.:
format)                 school/topics#create {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                 new_school_forum_topic GET    /forum/:forum_id/topics/ne
w(.:format)             school/topics#new {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                edit_school_forum_topic GET    /forum/:forum_id/topics/:i
d/edit(.:format)        school/topics#edit {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                     school_forum_topic GET    /forum/:forum_id/topics/:i
d(.:format)             school/topics#show {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                                           PUT    /forum/:forum_id/topics/:i
d(.:format)             school/topics#update {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                                           DELETE /forum/:forum_id/topics/:i
d(.:format)             school/topics#destroy {:subdomain=>/.+/}
                           school_forum GET    /forum/:id(.:format)
                        school/forums#show {:subdomain=>/.+/}
```

when I access `subdomain.lvh.me:3000/forum/1-room-biology`

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"school/topics"}
```

here's `views/school/forums/show.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to new_school_forum_topic_path , :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-medium" do %>
 New Topic
<% end %>

<% for topic in @topics %>
<%= link_to topic.title, school_forum_topic_path(topic) %>
<% end %>
```

How do I do this correctly and/or what is the correct way to route all of this?

Comment: Is it forums_controoler.rb? Spell check, as it might be causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `new_school_forum_topic_path` needs to have the forum provided, eg. `new_school_forum_topic_path(@forum)`.

For more information on nested resource routing in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: No. `rake routes` tells you what you need to provide - in that second example, `school_forum_topic_path` matches `/forum/:forum_id/topics/:id` so you need to provide both a forum and a topic.